# Using PHP 5.6 with MAMP on mac El Capitan

Tags: php, mysql, macos, mamp

I'm trying to use PHP 5.6 with MAMP on my macbook pro.  I'm a beginner both with mac and with MAMP so sorry if my question is basic.

I can see in MAMP's preferences that PHP 5.6.10 is checked as the standard version.  But when I open a MySQL server in the Terminal and when I try a:

```
SHOW VARIABLES LIKE "%version%";
```

I get this:

```
+-------------------------+---------------------+
| Variable_name           | Value               |
+-------------------------+---------------------+
| innodb_version          | 5.5.42              |
| protocol_version        | 10                  |
| slave_type_conversions  |                     |
| version                 | 5.5.42              |
| version_comment         | Source distribution |
| version_compile_machine | i386                |
| version_compile_os      | osx10.6             |
+-------------------------+---------------------+
```

So I guess that I only have access to PHP 5.5.42.

I checked in the MAMP folder and PHP 5.6 exists.  So how can I use PHP 5.6 instead of the 5.5?

Thank you.

Comment: what does `php --version` return on your terminal?

Comment: I have: PHP 5.5.27.  Now I'm really confused... Do I need to install a new version of PHP?

Comment: Do you have a phpinfo on your MAMP that you can look up to see what version of PHP is being used by MAMP? The one on command line may be different.

Comment: On the start page of MAMP I have a phpinfo link that says PHP 5.6.10.  So I guess that when using MAMP I use php 5.6.  If it's the case then thank you for your help (and sorry if there was nothing to fix).